# Shorter way to mapDispatchToProps using React, Redux and TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm trying to figure out how to reduce the amount of boilerplate when using React, Redux and TypeScript together. It might be that you can't in this case, but wanted to see if anyone has ideas.

I currently have a component that dispatches an action that toggles a menu, alternating between showing and hiding it. To do this I've defined my class something like this (omitting code related to state, focusing on the dispatching of action):

```
import {Action, toggleMenu} from "../../actions/index";    

interface IConnectedDispatch {
  toggleMenu: (isActive: boolean) => Action;
}

class HeaderMenu extends React.Component<IOwnProps & IConnectedState & IConnectedDispatch, any> {

  constructor(props: IOwnProps & IConnectedState & IConnectedDispatch) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleMenuState = this.toggleMenuState.bind(this);
  }

  public render() {        
    return (
      <button className={buttonClass} onClick={this.props.toggleMenu(this.props.isActive)} type="button">
      </button>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: redux.Dispatch<Store.All>): IConnectedDispatch => ({
  toggleMenu: (isActive: boolean) => dispatch(toggleMenu(isActive))});
```

The action is defined as

```
export function toggleMenu(isActive: boolean): Dispatch<Action> {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => {
    dispatch({
      isActive,
      type: "TOGGLE_MENU",
    });
  };
}
```

It feels like it should be possible to reduce the amount of code required to accomplish my goal here. Being new to React, Redux and TypeScript I fail to see exactly how though. Specifically it feels very repetitive to write the action name, toggleMenu, over and over. For example twice in this part:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: redux.Dispatch<Store.All>): IConnectedDispatch => ({
  toggleMenu: (isActive: boolean) => dispatch(toggleMenu(isActive))});
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a shorter way. You can simplify a lot of your code.

Action - Original

```
export function toggleMenu(isActive: boolean): Dispatch<Action> {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => {
    dispatch({
      isActive,
      type: "TOGGLE_MENU",
    });
  };
}
```

Action - Reduced

```
export const toggleMenu = (isActive: boolean) => ({
  isActive,
  type: "TOGGLE_MENU"
})
```

Properties Interface - Original

```
interface IConnectedDispatch {
  toggleMenu: (isActive: boolean) => Action;
}
```

Properties Interface - Reduced

```
import { toggleMenu } from "./actions"
interface IConnectedDispatch {
  toggleMenu: typeof toggleMenu
}
```

MapDispatch - Original

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: redux.Dispatch<Store.All>): IConnectedDispatch => ({
  toggleMenu: (isActive: boolean) => dispatch(toggleMenu(isActive))});
```

MapDispatch - Reduced

```
const mapDispatchToProps = { 
  toggleMenu 
};
```

I can recommend this library [typescript-fsa](https://github.com/aikoven/typescript-fsa). It helps reduce a lot of boilerplate created by actions, especially async ones.

Comment: Great! Thanks @niba!

Comment: @niba how do you call `connect` for this?  Unless I declare `mapDispatchToProps` as  `const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch): IConnectedDispatch => { toggleMenu }`, `connect` doesn't infer the types correctly for me.  I would call it with `export default ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HeaderMenu);`...

Comment: I don't use standard `connect`. I have my special wrapper around `connect` that automatically retrieves types from `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` which I can put later into my container definition. Anyway I just tried to do `connect(state => state, { ...actions})(Component);` and I don't see any problems. What types does your connect don't infer correctly?

Comment: @niba I get a type error from react-redux when I remove some of the explicit types, e.g.: [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mikebridge/acde0aab22b9910601bb7bff613edbfb)

Comment: @mikebridge I pasted your code and I don't have any errors. What version of typescript do you have? I'm using 2.5.2

Comment: @mikebridge could you create a minimal reproducible repo? Maybe there are some issues with a different kind of typings

Comment: @niba Here's a version using create-react-app-typescript that doesn't work for me: [https://github.com/mikebridge/connect-test](https://github.com/mikebridge/connect-test).  (This one's TS 2.4.2)

Comment: @mikebridge it doesn't work because you have wrong typings, you should add `getCityInformation: typeof getCityInformation;` to `IHomePageDispatchProps`

Comment: @niba Ah, that seems to work---I see I misunderstood what `mapStateToProps` is actually doing.  Once I fix that I can get rid of the explicit return type on `mapStateToProps` too, and I no longer need the empty `HomePageOwnProps` declaration.  Much nicer, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`mapDispatchToProps` will accept an object of action creators instead of a function and automatically bind all them all to `dispatch`.

[From the docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options):

> If an object is passed, each function inside it is assumed to be a Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with every action creator wrapped into a `dispatch` call so they may be invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props

This allows you to rewrite it as:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = { 
  toggleMenu 
};
```

**Note:** I'm not sure what you would need to type this to (if at all) in typescript.

Comment: Dan Abramov has a video on this shorthand syntax [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-using-mapdispatchtoprops-shorthand-notation).