# typeScript react -redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I want to use React-Redux with typeScript to dipatch an action,But when I use `mapDisPatchToProps()`,I don't know how to define the type of `dispatch`,There is My code:

This is the component file:

```
    import * as React from 'react';

    import Content from '../component/content';

    interface Props {
      allCityInformation: {'cityName': string, 'img': string}[];
      onGetAllCityInformation: Function;
    }

    class HomePage extends React.Component<Props> {

      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.onGetAllCityInformation();
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Content/>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

export default HomePage;
```

And this is my container file:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import HomePage from '../pages/homePage';

export type DispatchGetCityInformation = () => void;

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: DispatchGetCityInformation) => {
  return{
    onGetAllCityInformation: dispatch(getCityInformation())
  };
};
export default connect(() => {return {};
}, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage);
```

Now, the error information is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZjXf.png)

So,How to solve this problem?

Comment: Check this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46055018/shorter-way-to-mapdispatchtoprops-using-react-redux-and-typescript

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
/*other code*/
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<object>) => ({
  asyncRequest: (name: string) => dispatch(someAction(name)),
  otherAction: () => dispatch(someAction())
});
```